# Can't pass extra data from Payment Fragment on Poynt

Tags: java, android, sdk, pos

I'm working on an app for the Poynt POS system and I'm trying to integrate a custom payment like shown in their example found [here](https://poynt.github.io/developer/onterminal/integrating-gift-cards-and-custom-tenders.html)

In that sample, in PaymentActivity.java, there's some code that creates an intent when the payment has been collected, adds some extra data to it, and sends it:

```
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Transaction transaction, PoyntError error) {
    // Create intent to deliver some kind of result data
    Intent result = new Intent(Intents.ACTION_COLLECT_PAYMENT_RESULT);
    result.putExtra("transaction", transaction);
    result.putExtra("error", error);
    result.putExtra("test", true);
    if (error == null) {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
    }else{
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, result);
    }
    finish();
}
```

Back in the activity that kicked off the Poynt Payment Fragment, there's an activity result handler. This handler accepts an intent as a parameter but it appears that this intent is different from the one created in PaymentActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
            Payment payment = data.getParcelableExtra(Intents.INTENT_EXTRAS_PAYMENT);
            Log.d("ConfigurationTest", "Received onPaymentAction from PaymentFragment w/ Status:" + payment.getStatus());

            if (payment.getTransactions() != null && payment.getTransactions().size() > 0) {
                Transaction transaction = payment.getTransactions().get(0);
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
                Type transactionType = new TypeToken<Transaction>() {
                }.getType();
                //logReceivedMessage(gson.toJson(transaction, transactionType));
            }
        }
    }

    Boolean test = data.getBooleanExtra("test", false);
    Log.d("Sample", test.toString());   // this value will be false
}
```

The data parameter does not have a `test` extra field. It also doesn't have `transaction` or `error` either. Any idea why this is?

Comment: What is the `launchMode` of `PaymentActivity`?

Comment: `launchMode` by i mean in Manifest . Check under `<activity>`

Comment: No attribute for launchMode on that activity so whatever the default is I suppose? Sorry if I'm not looking in the right place. I'm also very new to android development.

Comment: @ADM, I see how that could cause this. I'll try out the different launch types. Thank you!

Comment: None of the other launch modes worked. I think something else is intercepting the intent and changing it because it has an extra field, but it's not one of the ones that I set originally.